# lighttpd2 and php under fast-cgi returns 403 "Permission denied"

Tags: php, cgi, fastcgi, lighttpd

lighttpd2 is under development but it's faar enough to where i want to start using it.
I've overcome the hurdle of installing it and getting vhost etc working.

- PHP 5.6.6 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Feb 20 2015 17:27:21)
- lighttpd-angel/2.0.0 - a fast and lightweight webserver
  | Build date: Mar 17 2015 13:42:32
- Arch Linux | linux 3.18.6-1
- VMWare Workstation 11.1.0 build-2496824

However php gives me the worst headache.

`/etc/lighttpd2/php.conf` looks as follows:

```
if phys.path =$ ".php" {
        log.write "Accessing php file";
        fastcgi "unix:/srv/http/php.sock";
}
```

The sock used to reside under /var/run/lighttpd2/ but for access/debugging purposes I moved it to /srv/http where the entire doc-root is.

And this is what my `/etc/lighttpd2/lighttpd.conf` looks like:

```
setup {

        module_load [
                "mod_accesslog",
                "mod_dirlist",
                "mod_vhost"
                "mod_fastcgi"
        ];

        listen "0.0.0.0:80";
        listen "[::]:80";

        log [
                "info" => "/var/log/lighttpd2/info.log",
                "error" => "/var/log/lighttpd2/error.log",
                "abort" => "/var/log/lighttpd2/error.log",
                "backend" => "/var/log/lighttpd2/backend.log",
                "debug" => "/var/log/lighttpd2/debug.log",
                default => "/var/log/lighttpd2/error.log"
        ];
        accesslog "/var/log/lighttpd2/access.log";
        accesslog.format "%h %V %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"";

        static.exclude_extensions [ ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi", "~", ".inc" ];

}

include "/etc/lighttpd2/mimetypes.conf";
include "/etc/lighttpd2/vhost.conf";
include "/etc/lighttpd2/php.conf";

#docroot "/srv/http";
index [ "index.php", "index.html", "index.htm", "default.htm", "index.lighttpd.html" ];

dirlist;
static;
```

Not sure if I should comment out `static` at the end or not.

And finally, my "startup script" for php looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec 2>&1

PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=2 \
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=10000 \
LANG=C LC_ALL=C \
exec /usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -n -s /srv/http/php.sock -u www-data -U www-data -- /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

My logs are almost empty, but never the less here's what they say:

### Startup log from systemd

```
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30955]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: info (angel_plugin.c:166): activate
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30955]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: info (angel_plugin.c:177): done
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30955]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30956]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) server.c:765: Reached state: suspended (dest: down)
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30955]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30956]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) server.c:677: Try reaching state: stopping (dest: down)
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30955]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30956]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) server.c:765: Reached state: stopping (dest: down)
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30955]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30956]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) server.c:677: Try reaching state: down (dest: down)
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30955]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30956]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) server.c:765: Reached state: down (dest: down)
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30955]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30956]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (info) lighttpd_worker.c:141: going down
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30955]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: debug (angel_server.c:367): instance released
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30955]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: info (angel_main.c:94): going down
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: info (angel_plugin.c:166): activate
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: info (angel_plugin.c:171): activate: core
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: debug (angel_server.c:184): Instance (30976) spawned: /usr/lib/lighttpd-2.0.0/lighttpd2/lighttpd2-worker
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: info (angel_plugin.c:177): done
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: info (angel_main.c:90): parsed config file
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30976]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) lighttpd_worker.c:105: config path: /etc/lighttpd2/lighttpd.conf
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30976]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) plugin_core.c:1254: loaded module 'mod_accesslog'
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30976]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) plugin_core.c:1254: loaded module 'mod_dirlist'
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30976]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) plugin_core.c:1254: loaded module 'mod_vhost'
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30976]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) plugin_core.c:1254: loaded module 'mod_fastcgi'
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30976]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) server.c:765: Reached state: loading (dest: suspended)
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30976]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) server.c:677: Try reaching state: suspended (dest: suspended)
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30976]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) server.c:765: Reached state: suspended (dest: suspended)
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: debug (angel_plugin_core.c:638): listen to ipv4: '0.0.0.0:80' (port: 80)
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: debug (angel_plugin_core.c:679): listen to ipv6: '::' (port: 80)
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30976]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) server.c:677: Try reaching state: warmup (dest: running)
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30976]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) server.c:765: Reached state: warmup (dest: running)
Mar 17 17:14:21 ArchKB lighttpd2[30975]: 2015-03-17 17:14:21 CET: lighttpd2-worker[30976]: 17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (debug) server.c:677: Try reaching state: running (dest: running)
```

Error-log is empty, but `info.log` says:

```
17/Mar/2015 17:14:21 CET (info) server.c:58: Got signal, shutdown
```

`debug.log` says:

```
17/Mar/2015 17:12:29 CET (debug) server.c:677: Try reaching state: suspending (dest: down)
17/Mar/2015 17:12:29 CET (debug) server.c:765: Reached state: suspending (dest: down)
17/Mar/2015 17:12:29 CET (debug) server.c:677: Try reaching state: suspended (dest: down)
17/Mar/2015 17:12:29 CET (debug) server.c:765: Reached state: running (dest: running)
```

And `access.log` (after I've requested index.php) says:

```
192.168.253.1 192.168.253.130 - [17/Mar/2015:17:12:36 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 3744 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36"
```

### Access on files

If I comment out everything to do with **php**, I get the file as a downloaded object with the proper content of:

```
<?php
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 302 Ok', true, 302);
    print 'OK!';
?>
```

The `header()` mod is just to make sure that lighttp doesn't screw up the headers because it's CGI (it's happned before and this *should* not affect the end result in a bad way).

The permissions looks as follows:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data       84 Mar 17 16:40 index.php
srw-r----- 1 www-data www-data        0 Mar 17 16:47 php.sock
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root            5 Mar 17 17:06 wham.html
```

"Funny" thing is that I can request `wham.html` without a problem and it's owned by root, but according to the documentation only working should be run as non-root, which I am:

```
root     30975  0.0  0.6   5104  3140 ?        Ss   17:14   0:00 /usr/sbin/lighttpd2 -c /etc/lighttpd2/angel.conf
www-data 30976  0.0  0.7  52048  3760 ?        Ssl  17:14   0:00 /usr/lib/lighttpd-2.0.0/lighttpd2/lighttpd2-worker --angel -c /etc/lighttpd2/lighttpd.conf
```

### Where the hell am I going wrong about this?

My conclusion is that it's something to do with `php.conf`, because `log.write` never executes, or at least I can't see anything in any of the logs.

So I need help, badly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, the *"conf"* is more like a programming language executing things sequentially one row at a time. I forgot to try calling `/index.php` directly instead of relying on the `index []` to work.

This sad, `php.conf` checked if the **requested path** ended with `.php` before the `index []` function had rewritten the request from `/` to `/index.php`.

There for, changing:

```
include "/etc/lighttpd2/mimetypes.conf";
include "/etc/lighttpd2/vhost.conf";
include "/etc/lighttpd2/php.conf";

#docroot "/srv/http";
index [ "index.php", "index.html", "index.htm", "default.htm", "index.lighttpd.html" ];
```

to

```
docroot "/srv/http";
index [ "index.php", "index.html", "index.htm", "default.htm", "index.lighttpd.html" ];

include "/etc/lighttpd2/mimetypes.conf";
include "/etc/lighttpd2/vhost.conf";
include "/etc/lighttpd2/php.conf";
```

Did all the difference.
**The order of config/execution is iportant!**

### Here's the original message from the dev forums

> Hi!
>
> The lighttpd2 config is basically a programming language, i.e. a list
>   of actions that are executed in order. Only a small set of these
>   actions are actually options that are set in the request context.
>
> If, at the time of executing the contents of `php.conf`, the physical
>   path doesn't end in ".php" it won't run the php; but it's only at the
>   end of the main config that you have it search for the index.php! (and
>   you didn't actually request "/index.php", the request was just for
>   "/") So:
>
> - vhost.conf should probably set the docroot in all cases; have it
>     also handle the "default" docroot.
> - either call index in the vhosts
>     you want it, or call it after vhost.conf to run for all of them; but
>     put it before "php.conf"
> - you can use log.write to debug the
>     contents of phys.path in php.conf before the if: log.write
>     "%{phys.path}";
>
> Btw: the howto shows the correct order :)
>
> I usually put (almost) everything into vhost configurations (see
>   http://doc.lighttpd.net/lighttpd2/mod_vhost.html for handling default
>   vhosts and the generic concept); I especially activate php only in the
>   blocks I really want it; you can define aliases for common config
>   actions (like the php howto is demonstrating).

-- stbuehler